# Is acidic character related to reducing power?

Tags: acid-base, redox, periodic-trends

My book says that the acidic character of halogen acids increases on going down the group because the bond strength decreases, making it easier to release the $\ce{H+}$.

But I also know that $\ce{HI}$ (considering the last element) is a strong reducing agent. Is there any way to explain this?

Won't "release of $\ce{H+}$" be equivalent to "accepting electron" (get reduced, i.e. act as oxidizing agent)? Am I wrong in saying so? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

An Acidic compound donates protons (Lowry Brönsted definition)
$$\ce{HI -> H+ + I-}$$
By releasing $\ce{H+}$, you need to note that the compound as a whole releases the proton. A reducing/oxidizing agent **donates/accepts electrons into it's own shells**, differentiating it from an acid.
$$\ce{2HI + 2OH- -> 2H2O + I2 + 2e-}$$

Here, $\ce{I-}$ donates two electrons to form $\ce{I2}$, thereby being a reducing agent.

Comment: Why do we, then, call HI a strong reducing agent?

Comment: Because of the second reaction I mentioned: it has the ability to donate electrons rather easily and form $\ce{I2}$

Comment: I doubt that HI may react with OH- to produce I2 as written by Aniruddha Deb.Most probably HI and OH- get neutralized and yield H2O and I-.

Comment: @Arnav Das It is rather a weak reducing agent. The reduction is not because HI is acidic, but because of I- being able to be oxidized to I2.

Answer (score 0):

No. Acidic character is not related to reducing power. For example, nitric acid $\ce{HNO3}$ has no reducing properties. It is a strong acid and a strong oxidant, able to carry out the oxidation of copper metal $\ce{Cu}$ to $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ion.

Answer (score 0):

Acidity as $\mathrm{pH}$ does affect many redox potentials.

But the compound acidic character itself has no direct relation to reducing power.

E.g. superacids like $\ce{HSO3F}$  or $\ce{H2F+ + SbF6-}$ have practically no reducing power. The former probably just against free fluorine or fluorinating compounds like $\ce{ClF3}$, the latter none at all.